# Match text exactly after n lines

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

Using regular expression match the text exactly after n lines.

In the below example, I want to ensure that ***request*** is exactly after 3rd line from ***id: 1***

**Example:**

```
signal {
   id: 1
   files: 1.bin
   major: 338013710701
   request {
      reqId: 101
      files: 1.bin
      major: 35723057325
      status: Sent
   }
   response {
      resId: 201
      files: 1.bin
      major: 27151510570
      status: Accepted
   }
}
```

**Note:** The value of ***n*** will vary based on the input(n may have the value upto than 100). where n is number of lines after which the string is present

I tried with the regular expression `/signal\s*{\s*id:\s*1\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\s*request/m` for the above example since n the value of n is minimal.

Can anyone help in framing the regular expression if n is 100?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What actaully the `n` means? number after the field reqID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{100}` quantifier indicated that the preceding `(\n[^\n]*)` should occur *exactly 100 times*:

```
/signal\s{\s*id:\s*1(\n[^\n]*){100}request/m
```

see [demo](http://rubular.com/r/ugpHoNMbKg)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\bid: 1\b(?:.*\R){3}.*request
```

Set case insensitive and dot does NOT match linebreak

In the above \R is a unicode linebreak.  Not supported in earlier versions of Ruby so, if that is an issue, substitute something like \n or whatever linebreak sequence is appropriate for your environment.